# Angle between a vector and orthonormalized base vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been looking at this probelm for a while now and I've come up with nothing.
It's a fairly simple problem from one of my old textbooks.

"Let **e1**, **e2**, **e3** be an orthonormalized base in the room. The vector **u** forms the angle $\pi$/4 with **e1**, and the angle $\pi$/3 with **e2**, what is the angle between **u** and **e3**?"

This question is bugging me since my lack of ability to solve it seems to point at something quite obvious with angles and vectors that I've missed.

So far into the book, only the most basic vector operations have been discussed.
I'm mostly interested in the thought process behind the solution rather than the answer itself.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\overrightarrow{U}=(u_1, u_2, u_3) $$

for each component we have:

$$\ u_i=|\overrightarrow{U}|\cos(\theta_i)$$

Now we compute the modulus:

$$\ |\overrightarrow{U}|=\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2}=\sqrt{|\overrightarrow{U}|^2\cos^2(\theta_1)+|\overrightarrow{U}|^2\cos^2(\theta_2)+|\overrightarrow{U}|^2\cos^2(\theta_3)}=$$

$$\ =\sqrt{|\overrightarrow{U}|^2[\cos^2(\theta_1)+\cos^2(\theta_2)+\cos^2(\theta_3)]}=$$

$$ =|\overrightarrow{U}|\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta_1)+\cos^2(\theta_2)+\cos^2(\theta_3)}$$

so you get this relation

$$\ \cos^2(\theta_1)+\cos^2(\theta_2)+\cos^2(\theta_3)=1$$

Now substitute $\ \frac{\pi}{4} $ for $\theta_{1}$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$ for $\theta_2$

See also http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Comment: I'm not familiar with the equation you presented at first, would it be possible to say something about it that I could at least google to gain some insight(name etc)? How did you arrive at the conclusion that it was the right way to go about solving the problem?

Comment: yes, sorry, just edited. Check if you understand now

Comment: see also here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Comment: Very helpful edit! So the reasoning is that you're breaking u up into its projections on the axises? The length of u does not actually matter since we're only concerned with the angles? I'm not 100% sure what you mean with the modulus step, it seems it would not be necessary?

Comment: The modulus step is just the explanation, the general rule is therefore that the sum of the squares of the director cosines is always equal to 1, so if the problem gives you two angles you can easily find the third

Comment: That final edit helped, now we're there. Thank you! :)
I also added the link to the answer since its a good resource for the topic. I'd vote you up but I've not got enough rep yet.

Comment: you'll get rep! have fun with vectors :)